# VBA Copy and Paste Range

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

I have a code that copies and pastes rows from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 based on a cell value in a Sheet 1 column. Sheet 1 has 20+ columns, but I only want 5 of those columns in Sheet 2. Is there a better way to write this code so I can replicate this copy and paste part of the code for different cell values?  That is, I have 5 lines of code I would like to reduce to 1.  I want to create multiple tables offset from each other on Sheet 2.  Columns are fixed and rows are variable. Currently, I'm having to repeat the code and specify exactly where to put my table in Sheet 2.

```
For myRow = 1 To LastRow

If (Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "E") = "TI002768E2XA E005") Then
    Set srcRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "F").Resize(1, 5)
    If Application.CountA(srcRange) = 5 Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCopyRow, "B") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "E")
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCopyRow, "C") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "D")
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCopyRow, "D") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "F")
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCopyRow, "E") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "G")
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCopyRow, "F") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "H")
        myCopyRow = myCopyRow + 1
    
    End If
    
End If 
If (Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "E") = "TI002768E2XA E105") Then
    Set srcRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "F").Resize(1, 5)
    If Application.CountA(srcRange) = 5 Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCopyRow1, "H") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "E")
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCopyRow1, "I") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "D")
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCopyRow1, "J") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "F")
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCopyRow1, "K") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "G")
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCopyRow1, "L") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "H")
        myCopyRow1 = myCopyRow1 + 1
    
    End If
    
End If

Next myRow
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array of source columns and destination columns. Then, use a loop to copy the values for each column. For example of your first part of copying should like below;

```
Dim srcColumns() As Variant
Dim destColumns() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

For myRow = 1 To LastRow

    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "E") = "TI002768E2XA E005" Then
        Set srcRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "F").Resize(1, 5)
        If Application.CountA(srcRange) = 5 Then
            srcColumns = Array("E", "D", "F", "G", "H")
            destColumns = Array("B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
            
            For i = LBound(srcColumns) To UBound(srcColumns)
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCopyRow, destColumns(i)).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, srcColumns(i)).Value
            Next i
            
            myCopyRow = myCopyRow + 1
        End If
    End If
```